# How do I align cell data in an HTML table with the image in the cell above it?

Tags: html, css, image, alignment, html-table

I'm making a web page that will help me revise my computer science class this year, and on the page I'm making it so when you scroll down there are 2 images, with headings and descriptions of what these the other pages will consist of.

However, the images don't appear on center with all of the text, although I have aligned it center.

What I'm asking is how do I get each cell of data in a HTML table to be center to the cell of data above it. I would post a picture but I need 10 reputation. Here is my code:

```html
<div class="Main">
  <br />
  <br />
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="">
          <input type="image" id="Topics" position:absolute style="height:px; width:px;" src="./CSImages/Topics.PNG">
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="">
          <input type="image" id="Languages" position:absolute style="height:px; width:px;" src="./CSImages/Languages.PNG">
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <H2 align=c enter>Topics</h2> 
      </td>
      <td>
        <H2 align=c enter>Languages</H2>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Here you will find Edexcel specification topics, it ranges from binary to compression to encryption</td>
      <td>Here you will find a few of the main computer languages used in computing today, such as; Python, C#, HTML and plenty more...</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You haven't aligned _anything_ `center`.

Comment: Make sure you use CSS for this(narawas answers) in the future as the html `align` is depreciated. http://www.codehelp.co.uk/html/deprecated.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean that you want to center all the text and your picture? You can just add `td { text-align: center; }` to your CSS file.

If you want to use inline styles, you can just add `style="text-align: center;"` to the `<table>` element.

The `text-align` CSS property is inherited, so you don't have to repeat it on every child element.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks pal, i did try doing this but i must have missed something out...Thank you for answering a such difficult worded question! :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, styling attributes are no longer used in HTML. It's considered bad practice because HTML is supposed to describe the content of the page, not its appearance. This means attributes like `color`, `border` or `align` shouldn't be used. Instead, styling is done with CSS. Now in your page you're doing a bit of both. But the reason why it didn't work is simply because you put a space in center and didn't even use "quotes". And you only wrote that on the h2 elements.

You should be doing what Narawa Games said instead anyway.
CSS text-align is what you need.

You also have this:
`position:absolute style="height:px; width:px;"`
Which doesn't make sense. You probably meant to put the position code inside the style attribute, and if you're not resizing the height and width I don't see why you left `height:px; width:px;` in there. In fact that whole part is useless.

I don't know why you're using the input element for the images. You might have your reasons, but then why wrap the input with an <a> element? I don't know. In any case, both img and input tags are autoclosing, so you should write them with a slash at the end, like this: `<tagname />`. Most browsers will try to fix that mistake and you won't see the difference, but it's bad practice not to close them. Your elements should also be in lowercase. You wrote `<H2>` instead of `<h2>`.